# Showing web page content based on user's access rights

Tags: asp.net

I have several ASP.NET pages with the same behavior:

1. Each page has their own content (e.g. forms and tables)
2. Each page links to 2 web user control files to display the menu frame
3. On `Page_Init`, there is a checking whether the user has access to view the content. If they don't have access, the page will show a message and will not show the remaining content. The menu frame will still be displayed.

I'm quite new in ASP.NET so I can only think of playing with the visibility of `<div>` tags for the content based on the access right. I would like to know if there's any other ways to work on it. I'm using VB for the code behind. Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap sections in a `PlaceHolder` and simply turn it off, for example:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AuthUserStuff" runat="server">
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In your codebehind you can simply do something like:

```
AuthUserStuff.Visible = User.IsAuthenticated;
```

`PlaceHolder` has the added advantage that the contents will NOT render to the client if hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Using a div tag that you control visibility on is bad, that means the user can just do a "view source" and all the content will be there.

You should instead not add the content to whatever control you using (Or use the control @Lloyd describes) or [redirect him](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to a custom 403 page ( No access).